# How can I change the wallpaper from command line when using dark mode?

Tags: command-line, gnome, themes, desktop-background

Can anyone please tell me how can I change the wallpaper for the dark mode from the command line?
I was trying to change my wallpaper from command line and I came across these commands,

```
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/background/picture-uri "'file:///your/image/path'"

gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri 'file:///your/image/path'
```

These commands works fine but it only changes the wallpaper when I'm in the light mode as soon as I change to the dark mode it automatically changes to a different wallpaper and these commands don't work when I'm in the dark mode. If I'm in the dark mode and I run these commands the wallpaper remains the same and when I change back to the light mode the wallpaper changes to the one I was trying to set when I was in the dark mode.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add picture-uri-dark, commands given below work for the dark theme.

```
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/background/picture-uri-dark "'file:///your/image/path'"

gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri-dark 'file:///your/image/path'
```